# Django regroup by upper and lower case

Tags: python, django, templates, frontend, alphabetical

I have a project in django, where I have to display clients in alphabetical order but names of companies can start from upper or lower case.

For now my solution below display names starts from lower case in one section and name starts from the same letter, but uppercase in another section.

```
        {% regroup clients by title.0 as clients_list %}
          {% for client in clients_list %}
            {{ client.grouper }}
              {% for item in client.list %}
                  {% if item.client_link %}
                        <a href="{{ item.client_link }}">{{ item.title }}</a> 
                  {% else %}
                        {{ item.title }}
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

How to display name starts from upper and lower case under one section?

Answer (score 0):

Using Django built-in template filter called title
{{ item.title|title }} {% else %} {{ item.title|title }}

Comment: This is not solution. Still I have upper and lower like a headers, I want to have one letter like a header and below upper and lower case names of clients